# Altium Designer - Parameter for the current day of the week

Tags: altium

I am currently using the value "=CurrentDate" as one of my parameters, however I would also like to include the day of the week as well. I checked Altium's documentation but couldn't find anything for displaying the day of the week. My current display shows in the form of "mm/dd/yyyy" but I would like the display to show "day_of_the_week, mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible out of the box. You could use a script to update a custom parameter (which you can add in the project options) insider the project file. The project file is in an INI-like format with sections, keys and values. Kind of a hack though, but it works, I used it similar purposes.